# Karate - When i run a basic feature with get call, i get karate exception as INSTANCE on the line where get is called

Tags: get, cucumber, karate

I have a simple karate feature file where i use get call to a particular rest api and i get the following exception,

com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: JOBS.feature:16 - INSTANCE

Does anyone know or come across this type of exception. There are no other information about the exception in the report.

It has JWT token authentication. So I have sent authentication token in the Authorization header.

Feature file is as below

```
Feature: API - scenarios

  Background:
    * def jwtToken = Java.type('utils.TokenGenerator').create(validClientId)
    * url baseUrl

  Scenario: Get template and create job

    Given path 'api/v1'
    And header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + jwtToken
    And header members = 'member_name'
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

I get the below exception

```
When method get 0.467 



com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: 

com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: JOBS.feature:16 - INSTANCE
```

Comment: If you can't give us any code or way to reproduce the problem, it will be really hard to help you.

Comment: Edited with the code